# Identifying Change in Column values only within same index values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this: https://github.com/thedatasleuth/New-York-Congressional-Districts/blob/master/newyork_total2.csv

I wanted to create a column called "Flipped" that would track a change in political party ***within*** the district across years located in column 'DOMINANT_PARTY'.  So for example, District 19 flips from REP to DEM from 2015 to 2016.  That's what I would want to track as a 'change'.  However, I wouldn't want to track a change between districts - so for example, I don't care that there was a change from REP to DEM between District 1 and District 2.  I have written the following code so far:

```
for index, row in newyork_total2.iterrows():
    newyork_total2['Flipped'] = newyork_total2['DOMINANT_PARTY'].ne(newyork_total2['DOMINANT_PARTY'].shift().bfill()).astype(int)
```

But as you can see from my 'Flipped' column, it's not recognizing changes within districts.

Comment: Please provide a **[mcve]**. This means no images/links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach using a `lambda` with [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
f = lambda x: (x.ne(x.shift()) & x.shift().notna()).astype(int)

df['Flipped'] = df.groupby('DISTRICT')['DOMINANT_PARTY'].apply(f).values
```

#### Update - Explanation

The `lambda` here is shorthand for the function

```
def flipped(x):
    return x.ne(x.shift()) & x.shift().notna()
```

The function takes a `Series` - in this case `['DOMINANT_PARTY']`.

Let's look at the district where there is a 'flip' to explain (District 19):

```
    DISTRICT  Year DOMINANT_PARTY  ...
90        19  2014            REP  ...
91        19  2015            REP  ...
92        19  2016            DEM  ...
93        19  2017            DEM  ...
94        19  2018            DEM  ...
```

Here our `x` having the function applied is the Series:

```
90    REP
91    REP
92    DEM
93    DEM
94    DEM
```

and `x.shift()` is:

```
90    NaN
91    REP
92    REP
93    DEM
94    DEM
```

The first logical expression in function `f` compares these Series with the [`Series.ne`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ne.html) method (not equal) which would be:

```
90    REP   !=   NaN    True
91    REP   !=   REP    False
92    DEM   !=   REP    True
93    DEM   !=   DEM    False
94    DEM   !=   DEM    False
```

Notice how we have 2 `True` values, as the first line - 'REP' is indeed not equal to NaN.
This is why we have the second logical expression to satisfy `x.shift()` is NOT equal to `NaN` (`x.shift().notna()`).
The `&` operator is the logical AND statement, requiring both of these conditions to be satisfied.

```
90    REP   !=   NaN    False
91    REP   !=   REP    False
92    DEM   !=   REP    True
93    DEM   !=   DEM    False
94    DEM   !=   DEM    False
```

Comment: This works but is a little bit beyond my comprehension/skillset currently.  I understand how lambda x: works but confused with the layers of how f is defined.  Explanation not required but greatly appreciated!

Comment: @thedatasleuth No problem, I've added an explanation. I hope that it helps, please let me know if you want me to clarify anything.

Comment: Thank you so much - your detailed explanation really helped me understand the solution better.  Understanding is key to improvement!

Comment: @thedatasleuth absolutely :) happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

you can use `groupby.transform`

```
def find_flip(group):
    return (group.shift(1).notna() & (group != group.shift(1)))
```

this function calculates whether there is a flip in a Series

```
df["FLIPPED"] = df.groupby("DISTRICT")['DOMINANT_PARTY'].transform(find_flip)
```

Comment: This is really beautiful and easy to understand.